# How to loop through each row in pandas dataframe and set values equal to nan after a threshold is surpassed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5 
 A  5   5   10  9   4   5
 B  10  10  10  8   1   1
 C  8   8   0   9   6   3
 D  10  10  11  4   2   9
 E  0   9   1   5   8   3
```

If I set a threshold of 7, how do I loop through each row and set the values after the threshold is no longer met equal to np.nan such that I get a data frame like this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5 
 A  5   5   10  9  NaN NaN
 B  10  10  10  8  NaN NaN
 C  8   8   0   9  NaN NaN
 D  10  10  11  4   2   9
 E  0   9   1   5   8  NaN
```

Where everything after the last number greater than 7 is set equal to np.nan.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try this:

```
df.where(df.where(df > 7).bfill(axis=1).notna())
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2  3    4    5
A   5   5  10  9  NaN  NaN
B  10  10  10  8  NaN  NaN
C   8   8   0  9  NaN  NaN
D  10  10  11  4  2.0  9.0
E   0   9   1  5  8.0  NaN
```

Comment: Nice one and did not notice we can do bfill :-)

Comment: @ScottBoston: Since you wondered on my answer, I want to give you an explanation. If you check on the timing of my edit history, you will see that I posted the `bfill` solution before yours. Right after posted I just realized I overlooked the question, so I took it down to work on the fix. I never see your solution until after I complete the fix and testing and undeleted the answer

Comment: @ScottBoston: we're cool. :) I see the comment disappears, but I thought it is SO moderator deleted it, not you. Therefore, I want to give you the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

A very nice question , reverse the order then `cumsum` the one equal to 0 should be NaN

```
df.where(df.iloc[:,::-1].gt(7).cumsum(1).ne(0))
    0   1   2  3    4    5
A   5   5  10  9  NaN  NaN
B  10  10  10  8  NaN  NaN
C   8   8   0  9  NaN  NaN
D  10  10  11  4  2.0  9.0
E   0   9   1  5  8.0  NaN
```

Comment: I came up with this one also, `df.where((df>7).iloc[:,::-1].cummax(axis=1))`

Answer (score 3):

create a mask `m` by using `df.where` on `df.gt(7)` and `bfill` and `isna`. Finally, indexing `df` using `m`

```
m = df.where(df.gt(7)).bfill(1).notna()

df[m]

Out[24]:
    0   1   2  3    4    5
A   5   5  10  9  NaN  NaN
B  10  10  10  8  NaN  NaN
C   8   8   0  9  NaN  NaN
D  10  10  11  4  2.0  9.0
E   0   9   1  5  8.0  NaN
```